# Will an international EFT reach my account even though I got the bank address and code wrong?

Tags: eft

I have provided with all the correct bank details but my bank address is wrong and last three digit of swift code of my bank is of same bank but of another branch. Will I receive the money from EFT?

Comment: Why don't you call the bank and ask, how can anything we say be more valid than you can find out directly from them?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe. Maybe not. Who knows.... Depends on so many variables. You should ask the destination bank how they'd handle it.

If not though you'll be able to recover the transfer at the origin and resubmit it correctly, but it will take a long time.

Comment: @keshlam depending on how the banks and branches structured, it may be crucial. I lived in a country where each branch was essentially an independent business unit with their own SWIFT codes and routing codes, and there was no guarantee that an account number would be unique across branches.

Comment: Ah. Didn't realize there were still banks reusing account numbers across branches. In that case, I sit corrected.